# Rails 6 on server getting a lot of "ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] /31194a065aebf1674b61.worker.js" requests

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpack

I have a rails 6 app on a server that's getting a lot of `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] /31194a065aebf1674b61.worker.js` requests. Does anyone know what the `xxx.worker.js` file is? JavaScript-wise I'm using webpacker with Vue.js. My guess is it's a webpacker thing, but I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the reason for this issue was with the Content Security Policy. It wasn't allowing a blob worker source. This was resolved by uncommenting `policy.worker_src :self, :blob` inside of the `content_security_policy.rb` file.